# Make MySQL default to a NULL when an enum field is set to an invalid value

Tags: mysql, html, sql

Is there a way to make MySQL default to a NULL when an enum field is set to an invalid value?

Also, is there a way I can specify a value in an HTML form such that, when saved to the DB, it stores as a NULL. I don't want to do any checks like "if empty string, then save a NULL." If it's possible, is it a good idea? Any security concerns?

My scenario: I have an HTML drop down menu that has an "null" option followed by a list of items that correspond to the DB's enum. When the null option is selected and saved, I want it to reflect as a NULL in the DB. Right now, it's being converted to an empty string, as per:

> If you insert an invalid value into an ENUM (that is, a string not
>   present in the list of permitted values), the empty string is inserted
>   instead as a special error value. This string can be distinguished
>   from a “normal” empty string by the fact that this string has the
>   numeric value 0.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html

Comment: Create a value in your enumeration the means "No Selection".

Comment: Not the way I want to go. Would be too much of a pain for the application to cater to.

Comment: Add a trigger that replaces all 0 strings (marker for invalid value) with NULL.

Comment: Is it possible to create a trigger that replaces all 0 strings in all tables for all enums? Would I be better off doing the ""if empty string, then save a NULL" check before making the insert/update?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"*If an ENUM column is declared to permit NULL, the NULL value is a valid value for the column, and the default value is NULL. If an ENUM column is declared NOT NULL, its default value is the first element of the list of permitted values.*"

On this basis, if you don't set a value for the field with your INSERT statement and you have declared the ENUM field to accept NULL, it will default to NULL.

**[EDIT]**

To address your comment, if you have this table definition

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` enum('New','Done') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

And your web application is attempting to UPDATE and existing record using something like this

```
UPDATE `test`.`tbl_test` SET `type` = NULL WHERE `tbl_test`.`id` =1
```

It will set the value to NULL.

You can reduce the risk of invalid enum data appearing in your HMTL drop downs by querying the table for the possible ENUM values to dipaly in the drop down. [Here's a Php example I found](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_enum/)

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `tbl_test` WHERE Field = 'type'
```

**[EDIT]**

To answer your additional comment, if you want the user to be able to select a NULL value and also allow an *empty string* as a valid value you need to sepecify your drop down like this

```
<select>
  <option value="-1">-- not selected ---</option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Book">Book</option>
  <option value="Music">Music</option>
</select>
```

By using the `<option value= ...>` attribute you can control the value POSTed to your WebApp and can then process accordingly. In this example a value of `-1` would be translated to NULL by your WebApp

Comment: NULL is allowed, NULL is the default. I don't think that excerpt deals with the default value being NULL when an invalid value is inserted. And I am setting a value for this field; it's coming from the HTML form. And I don't need to validated against "bad" data -- I actually want the HTML form to be able to set the field to a NULL.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add a code example. Perhaps I'm missing something from your question, but your issue is really with how your web app is handling the data

Comment: Yes, I understand that `SET `type` = NULL` will set the field value to NULL. The problem is that I'm getting my value from an HTML form. Is there a way I can send a NULL from an HTML form? If not, how do I get MySQL to accept an invalid ENUM value and default the field to a NULL?

Comment: OK, your WebApp will have to process the posted data and translate your <empty string> value into a NULL value. Are you able to make this change?

Comment: Yes, I can. It's just going to be a bit tedious. Was hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: Updated answer. If the HTML Form POST includes the field it will have to send a value. Your WebApp will have to check for a particular value and translate that to a NULL before calling UPDATE